# Cypress: Check if a newly opened tab has the correct URL

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress Cucumber for test automation. I want to check that a newly opened tab has the expected URL.

The .feature file has been written out in the Cucumber framework, and looks like the text below.

**When** I click on "[Hyperlink on website]"
**Then** A new tab should be opened with the URL "[New tab URL string]"

In the .js file I currently have what is shown in the image below. This checks the URL of the current tab, but I want to check the URL of the newly opened tab. What do I need to add to the Cypress command to do this?
[image: CypressExample.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress doesn't support multiple tabs as mentioned [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#:%7E:text=Multiple%20tabs%E2%80%8B,that%20opens%20a%20new%20tab.). We can get the href of the hyperlink and open the link in the same tab.

```
 cy.get(<Link locator>)
  .should('have.attr', 'href')
  .then((href) => {
    cy.visit(href)
 })
```

Hope this helps!