# How to fix cypress opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, cypress

I have been using Cypress to run a test on my site. When clicking a button it keeps taking me to a new tab and I can no longer continue my test with Cypress. I have already used the invoke function to remove the "target" aspect. I'm not sure what else I can do.

This is the current code I have:

[image]

I have already used the invoke function to remove the "target" aspect. I was expecting the new tab not to be opened but Cypress opened a new tab anyway.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide code as text, it is easier to read and work with,

Comment: It will also help us help you to understand the web app and how it is redirecting to a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does not support multiple tabs.

A workaround for this would be to opt to visit to the page taking the content from href.

Please check the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472140/cypress-check-if-a-newly-opened-tab-has-the-correct-url/75474403#75474403).